# How can I filter a list into three sublists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list called *transactions_clean*, cleaned up from whitespace etc., look like this:

```
['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Herbert Tran', '$7.29', 'white&blue', '09/15/17', 'Paul Clarke', '$12.52', 'white&blue', '09/15/17', 'Lucille Caldwell', '$5.13', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Eduardo George', '$20.39', 'white&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Danny Mclaughlin', '$30.82', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Stacy Vargas', '$1.85', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Shaun Brock', '$17.98', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Erick Harper', '$17.41', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'Michelle Howell', '$28.59', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'Carroll Boyd', '$14.51', 'purple&blue', '09/15/17', 'Teresa Carter', '$19.64', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Jacob Kennedy', '$11.40', 'white&red', '09/15/17', 'Craig Chambers', '$8.79', 'white&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'Peggy Bell', '$8.65', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'Kenneth Cunningham', '$10.53', 'green&blue', '09/15/17', 'Marvin Morgan', '$16.49', 'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'Marjorie Russell', '$6.55', 'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'Israel Cummings', '$11.86', 'black', '09/15/17', 'June Doyle', '$22.29', 'black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Jaime Buchanan', '$8.35', 'white&black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Rhonda Farmer', '$2.91', 'white&black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Darren Mckenzie', '$22.94', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Rufus Malone', '$4.70', 'green&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Hubert Miles', '$3.59', 'green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17', 'Joseph Bridges', '$5.66', 'green&yellow&purple&blue', '09/15/17', 'Sergio Murphy', '$17.51', 'black', '09/15/17', 'Audrey Ferguson', '$5.54', 'black&blue', '09/15/17', 'Edna Williams', '$17.13', 'black&blue', '09/15/17', 'Randy Fleming', '$21.13', 'black', '09/15/17', 'Elisa Hart', '$0.35', 'black&purple', '09/15/17', 'Ernesto Hunt', '$13.91', 'black&purple', '09/15/17', 'Shannon Chavez', '$19.26', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Sammy Cain', '$5.45', 'yellow&red', '09/15/17', 'Steven Reeves', '$5.50', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Ruben Jones', '$14.56', 'yellow&blue', '09/15/17', 'Essie Hansen', '$7.33', 'yellow&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'Rene Hardy', '$20.22', 'black', '09/15/17', 'Lucy Snyder', '$8.67', 'black&red', '09/15/17', 'Dallas Obrien', '$8.31', 'black&red', '09/15/17', 'Stacey Payne', '$15.70', 'white&black&red', '09/15/17', 'Tanya Cox', '$6.74', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Melody Moran', '$30.84', 'yellow&black', '09/15/17', 'Louise Becker', '$12.31', 'green&yellow&black', '09/15/17', 'Ryan Webster', '$2.94', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Justin Blake', '$22.46', 'white&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Beverly Baldwin', '$6.60', 'white&yellow&black', '09/15/17', 'Dale Brady', '$6.27', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Guadalupe Potter', '$21.12', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Desiree Butler', '$2.10', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Sonja Barnett', '$14.22', 'white&black', '09/15/17', 'Angelica Garza', '$11.60', 'white&black', '09/15/17', 'Jamie Welch', '$25.27', 'white&black&red', '09/15/17', 'Rex Hudson', '$8.26', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Nadine Gibbs', '$30.80', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Hannah Pratt', '$22.61', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Gayle Richards', '$22.19', 'green&purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Stanley Holland', '$7.47', 'red', '09/15/17', 'Anna Dean', '$5.49', 'yellow&red', '09/15/17', 'Terrance Saunders', '$23.70', 'green&yellow&red', '09/15/17', 'Brandi Zimmerman', '$26.66', 'red', '09/15/17', 'Guadalupe Freeman', '$25.95', 'green&red', '09/15/17', 'Irving Patterson', '$19.55', 'green&white&red', '09/15/17', 'Karl Ross', '$15.68', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Brandy Cortez', '$23.57', 'white&red', '09/15/17', 'Mamie Riley', '$29.32', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Mike Thornton', '$26.44', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Jamie Vaughn', '$17.24', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Noah Day', '$8.49', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Josephine Keller', '$13.10', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Tracey Wolfe', '$20.39', 'red', '09/15/17', 'Ignacio Parks', '$14.70', 'white&red', '09/15/17', 'Beatrice Newman', '$22.45', 'white&purple&red', '09/15/17', 'Andre Norris', '$28.46', 'red', '09/15/17', 'Albert Lewis', '$23.89', 'black&red', '09/15/17', 'Javier Bailey', '$24.49', 'black&red', '09/15/17', 'Everett Lyons', '$1.81', 'black&red', '09/15/17', 'Abraham Maxwell', '$6.81', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Traci Craig', '$0.65', 'green&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Jeffrey Jenkins', '$26.45', 'green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17', 'Merle Wilson', '$7.69', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Janis Franklin', '$8.74', 'purple&black', '09/15/17', 'Leonard Guerrero', '$1.86', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Lana Sanchez', '$14.75', 'yellow', '09/15/17', 'Donna Ball', '$28.10', 'yellow&blue', '09/15/17', 'Terrell Barber', '$9.91', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Jody Flores', '$16.34', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Daryl Herrera', '$27.57', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Miguel Mcguire', '$5.25', 'white&blue', '09/15/17', 'Rogelio Gonzalez', '$9.51', 'white&black&blue', '09/15/17', 'Lora Hammond', '$20.56', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Owen Ward', '$21.64', 'green&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Malcolm Morales', '$24.99', 'green&yellow&black', '09/15/17', 'Eric Mcdaniel', '$29.70', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Madeline Estrada', '$15.52', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Leticia Manning', '$15.70', 'green&purple', '09/15/17', 'Mario Wallace', '$12.36', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Lewis Glover', '$13.66', 'green&white', '09/15/17', 'Gail Phelps', '$30.52', 'green&white&blue', '09/15/17', 'Myrtle Morris', '$22.66', 'green&white&blue', '09/15/17']
```

These are transactions: name, cost, product, date. My job is to create three list (customer, sales, thread_sold (that's the color)) and filter the given list into these three. So the names only to the customer's list, the cost only into the sales's list and the product into the thread_sold's list. I don't need the date.

I made a code like this:

```
customers = []
sales = []
thread_sold = []


for item in transactions_clean:
  customers.append(item[0])
  sales.append(item[1])
  thread_sold.append(item[2])

print(sales)
```

I thought indexing the items in order would help, but it didn't work out. Also I don't know how to skip the dates.

Comment: How about `customers = l[0::4]` `sales = l[1::4] ` and `thread_sold = l[2::4]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with one line of code:

```py
customers, sales, thread_sold = [transactions_clean[i::4] for i in range(3)]
```

The list comprehension creates a list with three elements; each element is a list created from `transactions_clean`, starting at the i-th element and taking only an element every 4. In this way, when `i=0` you get only the names, with `i=1` only the prices and with `i=2` only the colors.

Then the list created by the list comprehension is unpacked into the three required lists.

Comment: Thank you, can explain a little, how this list comprehension works?

Comment: `range(3)` will generate `0`, `1` and `2`. for each value, `transactions_clean[i::4]` will start at the `i`th value, and step through the list, with step size of 4; So for names, it will jump from name at position 0 to next name at position 4 of the list. The loop, ensures you have three lists, each starting at the values shown above.

Comment: @NTFS I've updated the answer. @anurag `range(3)` generates `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: @PieCot my bad!

Answer (score 1):

You can use slices for that, assuming the order in the list is consistent. Slices work like this: `from:to:step_size`

```
end_idx = len(transactions_clean)    
customers = transactions_clean[0:end_idx:4]
sales = transactions_clean[1:end_idx:4]
thread_sold = transactions_clean[2:end_idx:4]
```

Just saw Mr. T's comment, you can leave out the end_idx:

```
customers = transactions_clean[0::4]
sales = transactions_clean[1::4]
thread_sold = transactions_clean[2::4]
```

Comment: Great solution :)

Comment: I mean... yeah, it's yours after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over your list by `for item in transactions_clean:` you get items for each list, so indexing them like `item[1]` would just give you string characters. If the order is always like customer -> sale -> thread_sold, you can do something like this:

```
customers = []
sales = []
thread_sold = []
for i in range(len(transactions_clean) // 3):
    customers.append(transactions_clean[i])
    sales.append(transactions_clean[i + 1])
    thread_sold.append(transactions_clean[i + 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code:

```py
customers = []
sales = []
thread_sold = []


for i, item in enumerate(transactions_clean):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        customers.append(item)
    elif i % 4 == 1:
        sales.append(item)
    elif i % 4 == 2:
        thread_sold.append(item)
    else:
        continue

print(sales)
```

This should generate your desired lists!

Comment: Thank you, what's enumerate stand for?

Comment: @NFTS enumerate kind of generates a count for the elements in the list; the count goes in the variable `i` and the actual element goes into `item`!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option I see is to use the list index and iterate with the `step` parameter of the `range` iterator to get the items 4 by 4:

```
for i in range(0, len(transactions_clean), 4):
  customers.append(transactions_clean[i])
  sales.append(transactions_clean[i+1])
  thread_sold.append(transactions_clean[i+2])
```

Here, `4` is the `step`, so values of `i` will go : 0, 4, 8...